# Black input backgrounds - Cocoa WebView

Tags: html, css, macos, cocoa

Morning everyone,

I've been developing and maintaining a Cocoa app which contains a WebView section. It's built against the 10.5 SDK to maintain PPC compatibility. With the most recent Safari update (came with the 10.7.4 update) all of the HTML input fields now have a black background. For example, this HTML shows up like this...

```
Username: <input type="text" name="username" id="something" placeholder="something"/></br> 
Password: <input type="password" name="password" id="somethingelse" placeholder="somethingelse"/>
```

[image]

I've played around with the "background-color" style and also played with a couple of the webkit styles I found [here](http://css-infos.net/properties/webkit) without much luck. The odd thing is that this page displays normally through Safari, just not though a Cocoa WebView. Does anyone have any suggestions on things to try?

Comment: Are you using CSS classes to generate the classes, or using in-line styling?

Comment: In this simple example I'm not using any CSS or in-line styling. The index.html page is exactly what's pasted. When I was playing with styles I tried both in-line and CSS.

Comment: You can still maintain ppc compatibility while linking against a newer SDK. The deployment target is the important setting in this regard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All.  As temporary workaround, please style your textbox with a border.  This is working for me:  border: 1px solid #000000;

Comment: Simple and very little risk. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Our application ran into the same thing, so I did some digging. It looks like WebKit was updated to use NSTextFieldCell to draw the field backgrounds instead of the older private API:

- [WebKit r104240](http://trac.webkit.org/changeset/104240/trunk/Source/WebCore/rendering/RenderThemeMac.mm)
- [WebKit r110480](http://trac.webkit.org/changeset/110480/trunk/Source/WebCore/rendering/RenderThemeMac.mm)
- [WebKit r116697](http://trac.webkit.org/changeset/116697/trunk/Source/WebCore/rendering/RenderThemeMac.mm)

The last revision looks closest to what shipped, but isn't exactly it (WebCoreTextFieldCell is lacking from the WebCore binary). Since the 10.7.4 sources aren't up yet, let's just assume this is Close Enough.

The important bit is that the NSTextFieldCell is being set to draw its background using [NSColor clearColor]. The desired effect, of course, is for it to render transparent and not cover up the contents below it. This assumes the compositing mode is set to NSCompositeSourceOver.

Unfortunately, prior to 10.6, NSTextFieldCell used NSCompositeCopy [[4](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/Cocoa/AppKitOlderNotes.html)]. Backwards compatibility with earlier applications was achieved by checking the SDK version, meaning that applications linked against an earlier SDK actually end up copying the clear color instead of compositing it. This ends up making the horrendous black mess.

Now that the issue is understood, we can get to the "suggestions of things to try" part. Here's some ideas:

- Wait for Apple to realize their mistake and ship an update.
- Swizzle -[NSTextFieldCell drawInteriorWithFrame:inView:] to not draw the background if the control view isa WebHTMLView. It sounds fragile and may have Mac App Store implications.
- Recompile against the 10.6 SDK.

I would definitely go for the last option.

Comment: Even better than sitting around hoping for a fix would be to file a radar, ideally reporting the number here for easy duping

Comment: 11454320, if anyone wants to dupe it.

Comment: Had one open before I asked - 11445540

Answer (score 4):

Maybe slightly safer, I found that adding `-webkit-appearance: none;` to the input element style works too.

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround. Add a css style property to input element: 
Opacity:0.99;